# Server-side include: An image link breaks within the included contents

Tags: server-side-includes, shtml

Suppose that folder B is inside of folder A.
Folder B contains:
    index.shtml
    a.html
    image.png
And, in index.shtml, I include a line

```
<!--#include file=“a.html” -->
```

And, image.png is referenced in a.html with

```
<image src=“image.png”>
```

When all are uploaded to a server and index.shtml is viewed in a browser, it correctly shows the contents of a.html with image.png in it.

Next, I move a.html and image.png out of Folder B and put them in Folder A. That is
Folder A contains
    a.html
    image.png
    Folder B
Folder B contains
    index.shtml
Now in index.shtml, the following line I used:

```
<!--#include virtual=“../a.html” -->
```

When all are uploaded to a server and index.shtml is viewed in a browser, it correctly shows the contents of a.html except that image.png does not appear with a broken-link image shown.

How can I fix the broken image so that image.png shows up in index.shtml?